# Matching whole between operator

Tags: .net, regex

Let's consider such text: `WHERE ABC() BETWEEN GetDay() + 1 AND 10 OR 5 <> 10`
I need to extract this: `ABC() BETWEEN GetDay() + 1 AND 10`

I am trying with such a regular expression `\sBETWEEN\s(?<=BETWEEN\s).*?(?=\sAND)\sAND\s` but I don't know how to select also `ABC()` on the start and `10` in the end (without touching `OR`). I started considering that it's not possible without adding some assumptions, am I wrong? How to extract it?

Comment: Try [`\w+\(\)\s+BETWEEN\s+.*?\sAND\s+\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%5c%28%5c%29%5cs%2bBETWEEN%5cs%2b.*%3f%5csAND%5cs%2b%5cd%2b&i=WHERE+ABC%28%29+BETWEEN+GetDay%28%29+%2b+1+AND+10+OR+5+%3c%3e+10).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that would be good point but what if instead of `10` is `SomeFunction() + 3`?

Comment: Then [`\w+\(\)\s+BETWEEN\s+.*?\sAND\s+.*?\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%5c%28%5c%29%5cs%2bBETWEEN%5cs%2b.*%3f%5csAND%5cs%2b.*%3f%5cd%2b&i=WHERE+ABC%28%29+BETWEEN+GetDay%28%29+%2b+1+AND+10+OR+5+%3c%3e+10%0d%0aWHERE+ABC%28%29+BETWEEN+GetDay%28%29+%2b+1+AND+SomeFunction%28%29+%2b+3+OR+5+%3c%3e+10)

Comment: wow, You're a magician! thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\w+\(\)\sBETWEEN\s.*?\sAND\s.*?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cw%2B%5C%28%5C%29%5CsBETWEEN%5Cs.*%3F%5CsAND%5Cs.*%3F%5Cd%2B&i=WHERE%20ABC%28%29%20BETWEEN%20GetDay%28%29%20%2B%201%20AND%2010%20OR%205%20%3C%3E%2010%0D%0AWHERE%20ABC%28%29%20BETWEEN%20GetDay%28%29%20%2B%201%20AND%20SomeFunction%28%29%20%2B%203%20OR%205%20%3C%3E%2010)

The `\w+` matches 1+ word chard (letters, digits or `_`) and `.*?\d+`  will match any 0+ chars (`.*?`) up to the first 1+ digits (`\d+`).

Comment: FYI: lookarounds in `BETWEEN\s(?<=BETWEEN\s)` and `(?=\sAND)\sAND` make no sense because your *consuming* pattern (`BETWEEN\s` and `\sAND`) already require the patterns (they must match, or there will be no match).